# Nginx rewrite simple issue

Tags: nginx

I've migrated my site and now got a huge list of links that I need to redirect to their corresponding new urls. I'm not a developer or sys admin and can't really help myself with the Nginx manuals.

A short snippet of my list looks like this:

```
rewrite /?tn=productview&c=34223&pid=8965214 /url1 permanent;
rewrite /?tn=productview&c=54424&pid=6180497 /url2 permanent;
rewrite /?tn=productview&c=54426&pid=2563446 /url3 permanent;
rewrite /?tn=productview&c=54426&pid=6889674 /url4 permanent;
```

The problem is that Nginx will in that particular case redirect the first line correctly and all following lines to "url1".

How should I write this so that each of this links be redirected to their corresponding new url?

Comment: There is no query part in `$uri` which nginx tries to match against your rewrite. Better do it in your application

Comment: Is there a way to write some sort of an "if statement" with cases for each individual URI?